# Specific filepath to store Screen Record using CGDisplayStream in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, core-graphics, screen-capture, screen-recording

I have been working on a c++ command line tool to record screen. After some searching I have come up with this following code. Looks like screen is being recorded when I compile and run the code. I am looking for functions where I can provide the specific filepath where the screen record is to be stored. Also I would like to append the timestamp along with filename. If anybody has better approach or method to this problem please suggest here. Any leads are appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    CGRect mainMonitor = CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID());
    CGFloat monitorHeight = CGRectGetHeight(mainMonitor);
    CGFloat monitorWidth = CGRectGetWidth(mainMonitor);
    const void *keys[1] = { kCGDisplayStreamSourceRect };
    const void *values[1] = { CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)) };

    CFDictionaryRef properties = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    CGDisplayStreamRef stream = CGDisplayStreamCreate(CGMainDisplayID(), monitorWidth, monitorHeight, '420f' , properties,  ^(CGDisplayStreamFrameStatus status, uint64_t displayTime, IOSurfaceRef frameSurface, CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef updateRef){});

    CGDirectDisplayID displayID = CGMainDisplayID();
    CGImageRef image_create = CGDisplayCreateImage(displayID);

    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoop = CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(stream);

   // CFRunLoopAddSource(<#CFRunLoopRef rl#>, runLoop, <#CFRunLoopMode mode#>);

    CGError err = CGDisplayStreamStart(stream);
    if (err == CGDisplayNoErr) {
        std::cout<<"WORKING"<<std::endl;
        sleep(5);
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Error: "<<err<<std::endl;
    }

    //std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do that in the callback which you provide in `CGDisplayStreamCreate`. You can access the pixels via [IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface/1419490-iosurfacegetbaseaddress?language=objc) (see other [IOSurface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface/iosurface_functions?language=objc) functions). If you don't want to do the pixel twiddling yourself, you could create a `CVPixelBuffer` with [CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456979-cvpixelbuffercreatewithbytes?language=objc) from the `IOSurface` and then create a `CIImage` with [[CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1547007-imagewithcvimagebuffer?language=objc) and save that to file as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896410/given-a-ciimage-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-image-data-to-disk).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how can I provide location in the callback in CGDisplayStreamCreate. 
Also in " CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, CFSTR("public.jpeg"), 1, NULL); " static string is required as destination that means I cant store it to the timestamp based filename. Thanks

Comment: @NikhilNilawar I don't quite understand the issue. The callback has a paramter `displayTime` which has the timestamp and you can just create a formatted string with `[NSString stringWithFormat]` with the timestamp and everything you need and pass that string to `CGImageDestinationCreateWithData`

Comment: I now understand how to create a timestamp based filename and location for storing a screencapture using CGImageDestinationCreateWithData. My original question is how to do the same for stream and not just a single screen capture.

Comment: @NikhilNilawar but you do not have a stream. If you want a video stream you have to encode the raw frames.

Comment: I am a beginner in Software Development. I thought CGDisplayStreamStart(stream) starts the stream.Can you suggest alternative approach to record the screen and save to a desired location. Any links to the same would be very useful. Thanks.