# CIContext JPEG/PNG output functions producing blank images

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image, ciimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am attempting to output a CIImage to disk, and am looking for the most efficient way possible. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53963575/251038), which suggests using the `writeJPEGRepresentation`/`writePNGRepresentation` methods of CIContext. However, whenever I attempt to use those methods, they produce blank images.

In the case of JPEG, it produces a pure black image. PNG produces a pure transparent image. The HEIF method also produced a pure black image. Same result if I use the `jpegRepresentation` or `pngRepresentation` methods which generate a `Data`, instead of writing directly to disk.

If I instead render these objects using `createCGImage`, and then write out the data from the CGImage, they look fine.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Here's a simple example that illustrates the problem:

```
let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: photoURL, options: [CIImageOption.applyOrientationProperty: true])!

let context = CIContext()
try! context.writeJPEGRepresentation(of: ciImage, to: FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("testFromCIImage.jpeg"), colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!, options: [:])

let cgImage: CGImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)!
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
try! uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!.write(to: FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("testFromUIImage.jpeg"))
```

`testFromCIImage.jpeg` appears as a blank image, with the same size as the original input image. `testFromUIImage.jpeg` appears identical to the input image.

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/clindsay/TestCoreImageOutput) that illustrates the issue, along with a few sample images.

**Update**

I have found only one condition where the image outputs correctly - when the source image is a PNG, and the `colorSpace` parameter of `writeJPEGRepresentation` matches the color space of the source image. I have not had success with any JPEG, even when the color space matches.

Comment: This is very odd indeed. Have you tried retaining the `CIContext` outside of the scope you are calling `writeJPEGRepresentation` in?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yep, I tried that, but no luck. Good thought!

Comment: Could you please post a bit more code/context or, ideally, a minimal sample app we could play around with?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel just updated the question with a sample project, and a little more information.

Comment: Hmm, I guess we have a classical "works for me" problem here: On my iPhone 11 Pro Max, iOS 13.41, all images are written and read again correctly... What's your test environment?

Comment: Of course, I was making a classic mistake and testing in the simulator and not on a real device. On a real device, it seems to work for me too. So I would guess this is just a bug with the simulator, unless you think there's any reason it would be expected behavior. If you want to write this up as an answer I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, this seems to be an issue exclusive to the Simulator. However, I did some more digging and found the following:

When inspecting what Core Image is doing (by setting the `CI_PRINT_TREE` environment variable) I found that the tree looks normal (though the resulting image is black). *However*, for the working configurations *nothing* was printed at all! That seems to me that Core Image is not actually doing any rendering but maybe Image I/O is used directly for writing the JPG.

Which led me to try forcing Core Image to use the software renderer (instead of its default Metal renderer) by passing `CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer` on context creation. However, this is totally ignored. The resulting context is still a Metal context...

So yeah, it seems the only feasible workaround is via `CGImage` right now. It would be great if you would file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Thanks for that extra digging, very interesting! I will file a bug with Apple for this.